# How to use ActiveRecord for a sql query with subquery in FROM clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Do you know how to translate a SQL query with a subquery in a FROM clause ?

Here is an example :

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    cars
WHERE
    cars.id IN (
    SELECT
        cars.user_id
    FROM 
        cars AS cf, (SELECT
        cars.user_id, MAX(consumption) AS consumption FROM
        cars
    GROUP BY
        user_id) AS t1
    WHERE
        cars.consumption = t1.consumption
        AND
        cars.user_id = 2
        AND
        t1.user_id = cars.user_id)
```

Comment: I have a feeling you're overcomplicating things here. Can you provide an example data set and an example result set from that data that you're trying to select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Car.where('id IN (SELECT cars.user_id FROM cars AS cf, (SELECT cars.user_id, MAX(consumption) AS consumption FROM cars GROUP BY user_id) AS t1 WHERE cars.consumption = t1.consumption AND cars.user_id = :user_id AND t1.user_id = cars.user_id)', user_id: 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, why complicate things when they can be simple?